# How to combine multiple two datasets using a for loop in R

Tags: r

I have two sets of data:

1. `dates` which contains all dates in 2017
2. `country` which contains 222 countries

I want every value of `country` to have all the `dates` in 2017. I created a for loop but the final output is only the last country in my list.

```
for(i in (1:222)){
  countries <- rep(country[i,1],365)
  final <- cbind(countries,dates)
}
```

Comment: Don't understand - rows is country and columns is date?

Comment: Country only contains 1 column which is the list of 222 countries while dates also contains 1 column which is the dates for 2017.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the `tidyverse` with a `tibble`, list-columns and `unnest`

library(tidyverse)

```
tibble(country = country,
       dates = list(dates)) %>%
unnest()
```

Answer (score 0):

to answer your specific question, i would use expand.grid():

```
dates = seq(as.Date('2017-01-01'), as.Date('2017-01-04'), by = 'days')
country = c('usa', 'brazil', 'austalia', 'sweden')

dates_country = setNames(expand.grid(dates, country), c('dates', 'country'))

# create list of dataframes by country for further manipulation
split(dates_country, dates_country$country)
```

this will give you the full factorial combinations of `country` and `date`.

but can't be sure if this is the best way to address your problem. i feel like if you're having to copy data multiple times, there's something else going on?

Answer (score 0):

With R base, you can use [`merge()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/merge.html) and make a Cartesian product (a `cross join` in sql)

```
merge(country, dates, all=TRUE)
```